# Is this a kind of wild mint?

Tags: identification, mint, invasive

Flower and smell of this invasive plant is like mint but the leaves are different- can anyone suggest the plant name?

[image][image]

Comment: I just saw the purple flowers...Dead nettle or Henbit...working on this.

Comment: What part of the world is this growing in?

Comment: Pretty sure its not dead nettle - there are at least three different weeds/plants growing in the image - I'd like to see a clear, in focus photo of the one with dark purple flowers that you're holding. Regardless, none of  the plants  in the photo is a Mint.

Comment: I also think that there are some confusion on plants. Could you take one and put it on a paper, and then do a photo? So all plant will be in focus, and we will see much more. I think one weed is Glecome hederaces (you see the flower on the bottom). But the large plant,  why not a Chenopodium?. To many weeds, so I think we are also much confused. And BTW you should tell us which region/continent.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi  The Chenopodium has green nubs for flowers...

Comment: Would it not be lovely if our 'clients' filled out a simple questionnaire before they formulated their question?  Just saying once again, stuff like zone, microenvironment, type of soil...whatever they are able to answer not only makes our job easier and less back and forth with the questions but the questionnaire would make the OPs aware thus being able to ask better questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are holding Dead Nettle I think, if it smells a bit like mint, purple flowers?  Lamiaceae. The other prolific weed is Chickweed...

[Lamium maculatum](https://www.summitpost.org/lamium-maculatum/409606)

Comment: I do not think it is the correct identification.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi  I am never attached to my IDs.  Please, help to find the correct ID!  What do you think?

Comment: @stormy - hard to say what it  is with the current, out of focus picture...

Comment: I would say not purple deadnettle.

Comment: I shouldn't have used that picture...definitely not purpurea!

Comment: I removed that picture, thanks, J. Musser!  Where have you been?  Aren't you sitting in front of a cozy fire sipping...hot chocolate?  Healing after this last season?